# RegEx find string between lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: regex

so I have this example string out of a html mail given:

```
Abholstellenname (Firmenname, Details): Musterfirma GmbH<br>
```

I'm using the following expression to find the company name, in this case `Musterfirma GmbH`:

```
(?<=Abholstellenname \(Firmenname, Details\): ).*
```

But I need to exclude the `<br>` tag following the company name.
How can I achieve this?

I would not ask here if I haven't read through the tutorials and still didn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=Abholstellenname \(Firmenname, Details\): ).*?(?=<br>|$)
```

The main idea is to turn the `.*` part into a `.*?(?=<br>|$)` pattern that matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible followed with either `<br>` or end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nxaAC8/1).

If the spaces can be any whitespace chars, replace the literal spaces in the pattern with `\s`.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to escape spaces with `\s` and escape parenthesis with `\(` and `\)`

`[^<br>]` matches any char other than `<`, `>`, `b` and `r`. This could work for your `<br>` but if you have anything after that, it will be captured again.

```
(?<=Abholstellenname\s\(Firmenname,\sDetails\):\s).*[^<br>]
```

Comment: These chars are already escaped, see the [original post source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76cf3d1e-9a1c-4c50-89f1-4c4809d1eb51/view-source).

Comment: I missed that part. on the `<br>` tag. I edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: The `[^<br>]` does not mean "anything but `<br>`". It matches any char other than `<`, `>`, `b` and `r`. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/8o41Y9/1) is the test proving this solution does not work.

Comment: I removed the `+` sign at the end. https://regexr.com/6tuue why does it work here and not in your link? curious.

Comment: It does not work and I [explained why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73712533/regex-find-string-between-lookbehind-and-lookahead/73712641#comment130165611_73712600). `Abholstellenname (Firmenname, Details): Musterfirma Tr` would truncate the last `r`. In `Abholstellenname (Firmenname, Details): Musterfirma Tbr`, last `br` won't get consumed. You can't use negated character classes like this for this purpose.

Comment: No, ***"`[^<br>]` excludes `<br>` tag"*** is a wrong statement. Again, ***`[^<br>]` matches any char other than `<`, `>`, `b` and `r`.***

Comment: The current version does not work for me, it still matches the <br>

Comment: Clark, in regex, there is no single construct that says "any text but a sequence of chars" other than `~()` in Lucene like regex flavor. Even a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) means something different, but it can be used to work around the limitation together with other features. In PCRE, the lack of the mentioned construct is by using [`(*SKIP)(*F)` "trick"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24534782/3832970).

Comment: Thanks! I learned something and I have bookmarked them. You are too awesome @WiktorStribiżew